# RecyclerView not always loading JSON Data

Tags: java, android

I am learning coding Android apps. Trying to parse a json to save the results in a RecyclerView, these are sometimes loaded and sometimes not while moving across activities or pressing home button and coming back. For the http call I'm using OkHttp. I have tried other solutions but none has solved my problem, even though since I am a beginner, I may be doing something wrong with the logic of operations.

```
public class VehiclesListFragment extends Fragment {  

...

private OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    final List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
    private String url = "myurl";
    final Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();  

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vehicles_recycler_view, container, false);

VehicleRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.vehicles_recycler_view);
 VehicleRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

 VehicleRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(),
                     DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

        updateUI();

        return view;

    }  


private void updateUI() {

        httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
                Log.d("Error", "Error!");
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    final String body = response.body().string();

                        try {
                            JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(body);
                            JSONArray Jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("models");
                            for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                                Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
                                JSONObject Jobj = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                vehicle.setName(Jobj.getString("Name"));
                                vehicle.setBrand(Jobj.getString("Brand"));
                                plane.setYear(Jobj.getString("Year"));
                                vehicles.add(vehicle);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                }
            }
        });

        Adapter = new PlaneAdapter(planes);
        PlaneRecyclerView.setAdapter(Adapter);
        Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The RecyclerView sometimes loads and sometimes not, expecially when moving across activities or pressing home and resuming.

I tried moving position of Adapter constructor and setting and error changes, but I don't understand what I am missing.
If you need more code I will provide it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the recycler view in the callback.

```
private void updateUI() {

    httpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
            Log.d("Error", "Error!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull final Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                final String body = response.body().string();
                vehicles.clear();// Removes all of the elements
                try {
                    JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(body);
                    JSONArray Jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("models");
                    for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
                        JSONObject Jobj = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        vehicle.setName(Jobj.getString("Name"));
                        vehicle.setBrand(Jobj.getString("Brand"));
                        vehicle.setYear(Jobj.getString("Year"));
                        vehicles.add(vehicle);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (null == Adapter) {
                            Adapter = new PlaneAdapter(vehicles);
                            PlaneRecyclerView.setAdapter(Adapter);
                        } else {
                            Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It seems working now! Could you explain me what Handler is doing in that lines? Thank you very much.

Comment: okhttp requests data in another thread, not main thread(UI thread).If you update recycler view outside of the callback, the data may not reach the client, but the recycler view has been updated in main thread, it will show nothing(You can verify this by printing logs in the previous code). So, wait for the data to arrive,  back to main thread(the handler does this work), update the recycler view.